# Python unittest: TestSuite running only first TestCase

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Running `first_TestCase` and `second_TestCase` separately all works fine.
But when i created TestSuite, it runs only `first_TestCase`. Why is this happening?

```
import unittest
from first_TestCase import first_TestCase
from second_TestCase import second_TestCase


     def suite():
         suite = unittest.TestSuite()
         suite.addTest(first_TestCase())
         suite.addTest(second_TestCase())
         return suite

if __name__ == "__main__":
     suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(first_TestCase)
     unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Comment: Doesn't `suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(first_TestCase)` cause that?

Comment: @Evert: Might be, but according to documentation it should "Return a suite of all tests cases contained in the TestCase-derived testCaseClass."

Comment: Which I interpret as returning a suite with test cases contained only in `first_TestCase`, not in `second_TestCase`. In addition, it appears your definition of `suite()` doesn't add anything, since it's never used anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(first_TestCase)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

You're loading tests from only `first_TestCase` right before you run via the `TextTestRunner`. You're never hitting that suite() function.

You should do:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite())
```

Because you're not calling the suite() function in your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(first_TestCase)
     unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

I should use:

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     unittest.main()
```

Comment: I don't understand how that fixed the issue.